# Embed/nest custom JSP tag to set the attribute value of another HTML tag

Tags: java, jsp, websphere, struts

I am new to Java and struts and I am working on a project where I need to set the value of an attribute from a custom tag which retrieve the value of a Java property.

```
...
<cust:urlGeneration porlet="<cust:write property="tgtPortlet"/>">
  <a href="<% wsp.write(out) %>"/>the link</a>
<cust:urlGeneration/>
...
```

This property is set in a Java class depending on the context. This code is in my corresponding java class :

```
if(isMyFirstUseCase)
  screenbean.setTgtPortlet = "portlet.myFirstValue";
else
  screenbean.setTgtPortlet = "portlet.mySecondValue";
```

But it does not work, the portlet attribute is not set correctly (the tag string is not interpreted).

I want the `porlet` property to be set either with `portlet.myFirstValue` or `portlet.mySecondValue` but I do not manage to dynamically set it...

Do I need to escape something or is it simply not possible ? Otherwise anyone has suggestion or alternative solution ?

I can provide any additional information if needed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it can help anyone, I found a workaround using JSLT :

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" %>
```

I set an intermediate variable with the value of my java class property using my "write" custom tag (Business requirement) :

```
<c:set var="varTgtValue"><cust:write property="tgtValue"/></c:set>
```

Then simply use this new variable to set my JSP tag's property using ${myVar} :

```
<cust:urlGeneration porlet="${varTgtValue}">
  <a href="<% wsp.write(out) %>"/>the link</a>
<cust:urlGeneration/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot nest tags this way; it would require recursive tag processing.

This is the same in XML–you can't use a tag as a property value for another tag.

Attributes should be set using normal JSP EL.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Would this work with JSTL ? Just like that : <jstl:set var="tgtPortletBis"><cust:write property="tgtPortlet"></jstl:set> and then just use "${tgtPortletBis}" to set my tag attribute ?

Comment: @LostReality Should, but using a tag to retrieve this value still seems odd to me.

Comment: The tags are from a custom customer component library so we are enforced to use it. I will test the solution and mark as solved if it works. Thx for your knowledge